# Error on cast from swift class to protocol

Tags: ios, swift

I have a piece of code:

```
protocol ModuleOutput: class {
    var output: Any! { get }
}

class SomeClass {
    var output: Any!
    init() {
        self.output = "ervwe"
    }
    func getIt() {
        let r =  (self as! ModuleOutput).output  
    }
}
```

And when code is running ,
I get an error:

```
exc_bad_instruction (code=exc_i386_invop subcode=0x0)
```

in this line:

```
(self as! ModuleOutput).output
```

What's my mistake?

Comment: You didn't conform `SomeClass` to `ModuleOutput`. Although this begs the question of *why* are you doing a `as! ModuleOutput` cast? Just access the `output` property normally.

Comment: The code I wrote as  example, in my current task is not possible to refer to the `output` on the line, and therefore I do.Now ,I rewrite Objective-C code to swift and there do cast from class to protocol: `result = [(id<TranditionalViewWithOutput>)self output];` and self don't conform to protocol TranditionalViewWithOutput -  and it's work.

Comment: Don't translate ObjC code literally to Swift. As Hamish wrote, conform to the protocol `class SomeClass : ModuleOutput` and remove the casting  `let r =  self.output`. And **never** declare instance variables  / properties which are supposed to be initialized via `init` methods as implicit unwrapped optionals. Prefer non-optional, if it's not possible use a real optional (`?`)

Answer (score 0):

totally agreed with Hamish and vadian here. ObjC casting and Swift `as?` are very different operations that achieve completely different things. In Swift, you must declare conformances.

The (more) correct code would look like this:

```
protocol ModuleOutput: class {
    var output: Any { get }
}

class SomeClass: ModuleOutput {
    var output: Any = "ervwe"

    func getIt() {
        let result = output
        // ... use result
    }
}
```

This is still likely wrong, because `output` should almost certainly not be `Any` (that's almost never the right type), but it's closer.

---

I don't quite understand your comments below, but you seem to suggest you have a class that informally conforms to `TranditionalViewWithOutput`, but does not *formally* conform in ObjC. That used to be very common in ObjC (prior to v2, when `@optional` was added), so it wouldn't be surprising in older code. But it's not a problem. Just conform it:

```
extension InformallyConformingVC: TranditionalViewWithOutput {}
```

If it already conforms syntactically, that just tells the compiler that it fully conforms. [(Swift protocols are not just bags of syntax.)](https://oleb.net/blog/2016/12/protocols-have-semantics/)

I'm not clear that this is really your question, but it's the best I can make out from the comments. Perhaps you should reword the question closer to your actual intent.

Comment: OK I understood. At this point in time I write an extension to the UIViewController class and I need to get the `ouput` field provided that the UIViewController does not correspond to any protocol, and I do not know its type. Can it be done?